# How to convert fetch to axios

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have the following piece of code which is working perfect. However, my task is to replace fetch with axios. can you please guide, what would be the correct replacement of code in axios?

```
const create = async (credentials, software) => {
  return await fetch('/api/software/create', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + credentials.t
    },
    credentials: 'include',
    body: JSON.stringify(software)
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json()
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
}

create({ t: jwt.token }, data)
    .then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        this.setState({ error: data.error })
      } else {
        this.props.dispatch(initSoftware()); //if successful get the list of softwares in redux store
      }
    })
```

The data variable is an object which hold the req.body equivalent... 
The above code is written in react and the create() is called within onSubmit eventhandler.

I am sure if I use axios the create() would be eliminated.. but how? Please guide..

Comment: you could check the docs for the axios. they are located [here](https://github.com/axios/axios). there is an example how to write a post request.

Comment: i think it is just a normal post (your fetch)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It shouldn't be too different than what you currently have but something like this...

```
const create = async (credentials, software) => {
  return await axios({
    url: '/api/software/create'
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + credentials.t
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    data: JSON.stringify(software)
  })
    .then((response) => {
      return response.data;
    }).catch((err) => console.log(err))
}

create({ t: jwt.token }, data)
    .then((data) => {
      if (data.error) {
        this.setState({ error: data.error })
      } else {
        this.props.dispatch(initSoftware()); //if successful get the list of softwares in redux store
      }
    })
```

Note that the data you would be looking for should be in a property called `data`.

For more, check out the API references [here](https://github.com/axios/axios).

Comment: I was expecting to reduce the code... so I wrote like the following but your way, could help me maintain the axios code in one reusable locations...     axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/api/software/create',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwt.token
      },
      credentials: 'include',
      data
    }).then((res) => {
        this.props.dispatch(initSoftware());
    }).catch(error=> console.log(error))

Comment: @Avinash, I see. Apologies, I thought your goal was to reduce the amount of refactoring while keeping the general requirement of switching over to `axios` from `fetch`

Answer (score 2):

2021 answer: just in case you land here looking for how to make GET and POST Fetch api requests using async/await or promises as compared to axios.

I'm using jsonplaceholder fake API to demonstrate:

Fetch api GET request using async/await:

```
         const asyncGetCall = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
                 const data = await response.json();
                // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
                 console.log(data);
               } catch(error) {
            // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
                  console.log(error)
                 } 
            }


          asyncGetCall()
```

Fetch api POST request using async/await:

```
    const asyncPostCall = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
                 method: 'POST',
                 headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                   },
                   body: JSON.stringify({
             // your expected POST request payload goes here
                     title: "My post title",
                     body: "My post content."
                    })
                 });
                 const data = await response.json();
              // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
                 console.log(data);
               } catch(error) {
             // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)

                  console.log(error)
                 } 
            }

asyncPostCall()
```

GET request using Promises:

```
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
   // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
   console.log(error)
  })
```

POST request using Promises:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
   body: JSON.stringify({
     // your expected POST request payload goes here
      title: "My post title",
      body: "My post content."
      })
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
   // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
  // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
   console.log(error)
  })
```

GET request using Axios:

```
        const axiosGetCall = async () => {
            try {
              const { data } = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
              console.log(`data: `, data)
           
            } catch (error) {
    // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
              console.log(`error: `, error)
            }
          }
    
    axiosGetCall()
```

POST request using Axios:

```
const axiosPostCall = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',  {
      // your expected POST request payload goes here
      title: "My post title",
      body: "My post content."
      })
   // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
      console.log(`data: `, data)
   
    } catch (error) {
  // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
      console.log(`error: `, error)
    }
  }


axiosPostCall()
```